# System.Argument exception in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to MVC and i am having a problem. I have one table named `tblEmployee` , model `Employee`. Controller `EmployeeController`.

My code for Model:

```
namespace MvcPractice.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i have created EmployeeContext.cs in Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcPractice.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: look at inner exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception tells you everything you need to know here. It is telling you that you don't have a provider called `Syste,.Data.SqlClient` which means you probably have a spelling mistake in your connection string. So this:

```
<add name="..." provider="Syste,.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Should be this:

```
<add name="..." provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: i respelled it. and now i am getting this exception

Comment: Now you have completely changed your question. You should leave it as it was, accept/upvote any answers that helped and if you still have a problem, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

you missed in connection string in web.config file,so once check to connection string

```
<addname=""connectionString="Server=;Database=;UserId=;Password=;"provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```